# Block rtmp and make it retry on port 80 via iptables

Tags: iptables, rtmp, squid

We have a proxy filtering connections but some sites use RTMP, which runs on port 1935. This cannot go through the proxy as proxies are port 80 only.

As far as I know if RTMP fails, it will retry on port 80.

So, how can I block 1935 in `iptables` to force RTMP to go through a normal HTTP port?

I have the following but it is not working.

Any RTMP streams still fail.

```
[root@li711-43 ~]# iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --destination-port 1935 -j DROP
[root@li711-43 ~]# iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 1935 -j DROP
```

Answer (score 0):

> So, how can I block 1935 in `iptables` to force RTMP to go through a
>   normal HTTP port?

Use the [PREROUTING](https://www.centos.org/docs/4/4.5/System_Administration_Guide/prerouting.html) chain:

```
iptables -t nat -I PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 1935 -j REDIRECT --to-ports 80
```

But that said, you also say this:

> We have a proxy filtering connections but some sites use RTMP, which
>   runs on port 1935. This cannot go through the proxy as proxies are
>   port 80 only.

So is port 1935 completely blocked? You would need to at least punch a hole in the FORWARD chain to allow 1935 to come through & then be sent to port 80 via the above PREROUTING rule:

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 1935 -j ACCEPT
```

Or if `iptables` is going to forward that traffic to another machine, you need to set that IP like this; replacing `123.45.67.89` with the actual IP address of the destination machine:

```
iptables -A FORWARD -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 1935 -d 123.45.67.89 -j ACCEPT
```

Comment: rtmp will retry on port 80 if 1925 doesn't work, so is there any need to forward it to 80?